# How to change the color of a single X axis value in a tikzpicture

Tags: pgfplots, color, axis, value

I want the symbolic x axis value a4 in red. How do I do this?
[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
symbolic x coords={$a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$,$a_4$,$a_5$}, 
ylabel=Y axis label, 
xlabel=X axis label,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
yticklabels={,,}
]
\addplot+[only marks, error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    ($a_1$,0.3) +- (0.1,0.1) 
    ($a_2$,0.5) +- (0.1,0.1)
    ($a_3$,0.4)+- (0.1,0.1)
    ($a_4$,0.55) +- (0.1,0.1)
    ($a_5$,0.47)+- (0.1,0.1)};

\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:$a_1$,0.55);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs:$a_5$,0.55);
\coordinate (O1) at (rel axis cs:0,0);
\coordinate (O2) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
\draw [dashed] (A -| O1) -- (A -| O2);
%\draw [dashed] (B -| O1) -- (B -| O2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be more elegant solutions. But you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
symbolic x coords={$a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$,\textcolor{red}{$a_4$},$a_5$}, 
ylabel=Y axis label, 
xlabel=X axis label,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
yticklabels={,,}
]
\addplot+[only marks, error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    ($a_1$,0.3) +- (0.1,0.1) 
    ($a_2$,0.5) +- (0.1,0.1)
    ($a_3$,0.4)+- (0.1,0.1)
    (\textcolor{red}{$a_4$},0.55) +- (0.1,0.1)
    ($a_5$,0.47)+- (0.1,0.1)};

\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:$a_1$,0.55);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs:$a_5$,0.55);
\coordinate (O1) at (rel axis cs:0,0);
\coordinate (O2) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
\draw [dashed] (A -| O1) -- (A -| O2);
%\draw [dashed] (B -| O1) -- (B -| O2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]